# Scan word document using php

Tags: php, laravel, docx, doc

I will be uploading .doc and .docx word documents, and i want to be able to scan through then and pick out certain keywords, i have been trying to find a PHP function that I can use but have no luck. I am using Laravel 5 as my framework if this helps. Really appreciate if someone has had the same issue as me.

Comment: I really don't think you did much research on this. I just googled "read microsoft word php" and found 6 million results

Comment: [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

Comment: For excel there is this cool plugin https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel